# Make Namespaced Controller#Action Respond to Both GET and POST Requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my `routes` file I have the following:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  namespace :foobarbazz do
    resource :blog, only: [:index]
  end

end
```

Currently the blog resource will only be directed to the `#index` action on GET requests.  Is there a way to make this namespaced controller action *also* respond to POST requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom router:

```
namespace :foobarbazz do
  resource :blog, only: [:index]
  post "/blogs", to: "blogs#index"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Also:

```
namespace :foobarbazz do
  match 'blog', to: 'blog#index', via: [:get, :post]
end
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#http-verb-constraints